# Cannot decrypt AES-ciphered data

Tags: aes

Guys, I have a problem with AES decryption.

The AES KEY and AES IV is below

```
byte[] aeskey = new byte[] {(byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xB1,
               (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xCD, (byte) 0xF6, (byte) 0x69,
               (byte) 0xF1, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xDE,
               (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0xC0, (byte) 0xEA, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0xF5};

byte[] aesiv  = new byte[] {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xCF, (byte) 0x3B,
               (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0x6D, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0xF2,
               (byte) 0xFA, (byte) 0xD6, (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0xA8,
               (byte) 0xF2, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFD, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0xBA};
```

and the cipher bytes

```
byte[] encryptedData = new byte[] {(byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x56,
               (byte) 0xB7, (byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xF6,
               (byte) 0x7A, (byte) 0xB2, (byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0x7E,
               (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x38};
```

I don't know which AES model and padding is being used, I used the jar of `bouncycastle` and tried the model one by one, it seems there is no one correct, I only know the decrypted data first two bytes must be `0x00, 0x00`.

Who can help me?

Comment: OK, just for fun tried ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB and CTR modes, all to no avail, for anybody who wants to try this before it is finally closed.